# django 3.1 user not staying logged in

Tags: django, django-views

So, I have a django 3.1 project and a Foo app that is going to have a user login, but I am running into the problem where users will not retain a logged in status after any additional requests. the code is similar to that below, but pretend that all relevant imports are made that are otherwise absent.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("Foo:stays_loggedin_check"))
            return render(request, template_name="Foo/loginfailed.html")
    return render(request, template_name="Foo/login.html")
def stays_loggedin_check(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, template_name="Foo/staysloggedin.html")
    return render(request, template_name="Foo/weirdly_doesnt_stay_logged_in_despite_documentaion.html")
```

urls.py
from django.urls import path

```
from . import views
app_name = "Foo"

urlpatterns = [
    path("login", views.login, name="login"),
    path("shouldnt_need_to_do_this", views.stays_loggedin_check, name="stays_loggedin_check"),
]
```

When one fills out the login form at Foo/login.html incorrectly it, as expected, renders the page Foo/loginfailed.html. but when filled out correctly this form returns Foo/weirdly_doesnt_stay_logged_in_despite_documentaion.html. Is there a way to model behavior to be in line with django documentation where this will return Foo/staysloggedin.html instead?

Comment: So, after a while I found out that the whole project wasn;t supporting sessions, upon further investigation this appeared to be because of missing cookies. 

As I was incorporating logins I incompletely added https support by adding
'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
'
to settings.py. I did not add any way for the project to actually send https, but told it it should only send session cookies through https. this made sessions impossible.

Answer (score 2):

So, after a while I found out that the whole project wasn;t supporting sessions, upon further investigation this appeared to be because of missing cookies. As I was incorporating logins I incompletely added https support by adding ' SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True ' to settings.py. I did not add any way for the project to actually send https, but told it it should only send session cookies through https. this made sessions impossible.